# How to show only matched result after filtering data from the database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, query-string

I am building bus ticket booking app in node.js
In this app I have created different tables like location table, route table and others

My location schema lokks like this.

```
const locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    departureLocation: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      time: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      subLocations: { type: [String] },
    },
    arrivalLocation: {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      time: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      subLocations: { type: [String] },
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

In this table only administrator can enter data about locations.
after inserting data to location table my mongodb location table looks like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbt8S.png
After entering data about location only admin can add data about trips(routes)
route schema looks like this

```
const routeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Location',
    required: true
  },
  duration: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  busId:{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref:"Bus",
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type:String,
    required: true
  },
},
{
  timestamps: true,
});
```

The route table looks like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UamRi.png
I am referencing location id table to location schema

But the problem starts now on
I want to show only matched results they enter in query string like:(http://127.0.0.1:3000/trips?departure=surat&arrival=bhavnagar&date=2022-05-30) all users (general users) but the problem is that I am getting all the results from the database

my get request is this:

```
router.get("/trips", async (req, res) => {
  if ((!req.query.departure && !req.query.arrival) || !req.query.date) {
    return res.send({
      error: "Please enter the data to get the trip",
    });
  }

  const { departure, arrival, date } = req.query;

  const locations = await Location.find({
    'departureLocation.name': departure,
    'arrivalLocation.name': arrival
  })
  
  const routes = await Route.find({
    locations,
    date
  });

  return !routes ? res.status(404).send() : res.status(200).send(routes);
});
```

I think it is only parsing the date but it skips the other parameters from query string.
I know something's wrong in the code but don't know where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the ids of locations in the `Route.find` with `$in` operator like this:

```
const ids = locations.map(l => l._id);
const routes = await Route.find({
    $and: [
        { location: { $in: ids }},
        { date },
    ]
});
```

Also make sure the `Location.find` returns the locations you expect. So try `console.log(locations)` before `Route.find`

Comment: Thank you so much @Molda this worked!!!  BTW what do you think about the database design. Is it good or It needs to be changed. https://stackoverflow.com/users/3284355/molda

Comment: @Mitul_kheni You're welcome. I'm more into relational dbs like postgre mysql etc. so can't help you with the db design. Although i would probably use `from / to` instead of `departureLocation / arrivalLocation`